# Why android build system is working in a strange way?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have this xml file which has the following structure:

```
<RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView above="@id/bottom">...</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout id="@+id/bottom">...</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I referenced the linear layout in the scroll view above. At first the project compiles successfully with no errors and gave the desired results. But when I clean the project it gave errors for the linear layout reference.
**Error:(16, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/bottom').**

I know, I should put Linear Layout above the scroll view but why the errors didnt show up at first,

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Post your errors.

Comment: check my post, I have edited it @Dipalishah

Comment: Is this the only error or are there others as well?

Comment: kindly share your xml file source code. then we can find out issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like

```
<RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout id="@+id/bottom">...</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView above="@id/bottom">...</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or

```
<RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView above="@+id/bottom">...</ScrollView> <!-- notice the + -->
<LinearLayout id="@+id/bottom">...</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in `RelativeLayout`, order doesn't matter as views are in relation with each other. so in your actual xml, your LinearLayout is defined below ScrollView & hence it is not able to find it when you say `above="@id/bottom"`. so either swap the position or add "+" before `above="@id/bottom"` like: `above="@+id/bottom"`

Comment: I didnt ask for the solution, I asked for the strange behaviour, read my question again.

Comment: @MMonisAhmedKhan you edited your question after my answer, so earlier I assumed you were facing problem & meanwhile I was giving explanation I believe you down voted :)

Comment: can you tell how adding the '+' sign solves the problem?

Comment: as I said, when you say above="@id/...", parser assumes that the id is already defined, which is actually not because you are defining that id below the ScrollView so it fails. Now when you add +, it creates the id if not found & now when your LinearLayout does it again like <LinearLayout id="@+id/bottom">, it doesn't generate it again as it's already been done by "above="@+id/"